# Can I simplify $x=\frac{\ln(|\mathcal F((\mathcal F^{-1}(\sqrt{(f^{-5/3})}))^{2})|)}{\ln(f)}$

Tags: power-spectral-density

Given a variable in time $u_{k}$, and an other variable f which represents the frequencies in a range [a,b]:

$$|\mathcal F \left \lbrace u_{k}\right \rbrace |^{2}=f^{-5/3}\tag{1}$$

where $\mathcal F$ stands for fast Fourier transform.

Now, I want to find $x$ knowing that:

$$|\mathcal F \left \lbrace u_{k}^{2}\right \rbrace|= f^{x}\tag{2}$$

I can isolate $x$ as:

$$x=\frac{\ln(|\mathcal F \left \lbrace u_{k}^{2}\right \rbrace |)}{\ln(f)}\tag{3}$$

I can find $u$ using (1):

$$u=\mathcal F^{-1}(\sqrt{(f^{-5/3})}) \tag{4}$$

On the consequence $x$ is:

$$x=\frac{\ln(|\mathcal F \left \lbrace ( \mathcal F^{-1} \left \lbrace \sqrt{(f^{-5/3})} \right \rbrace )^{2} \right \rbrace|)}{\ln(f)} \tag{5}$$

Is there any way in which I can simplify $x$?? I am stuck with this problem for a lot of weeks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a potential starting point: it is considered  that when a function behaves as a power law  ($x(t) \sim t^\alpha, t> 0$), then its magnitude spectrum as well, with $|X(f)| \sim f^{-(1+\alpha)}$. One can see for instance:

- [Computing Fourier transform of power law](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2173780/257503)
- [An Interesting Fourier Transform - 1/f Noise](https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/40.php)
- Sketches of a "proof" and references (since there are  convergence issues) are provided in an answer to [I cannot find reference (paper) of this relation $u(t)t^{α} ↔^{FT} f^{-(α+1)}$](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/74315/15892).

If I plug that in your case, since $|X(f)|^2 \sim f^{-5/3}$, so we seek $-5/6=-(1+\alpha)$. I obtain $\alpha = -\frac{1}{6}$. So you would have $x^2(t) \sim t^{2\alpha}$, with a magnitude spectrum $|\chi(f)|$ in $f^{-(1-\frac{1}{3})}$, or $f^{-\frac{2}{3}}$.

Now, is the discrete signal sufficiently well-sampled and clean to verify it in the discrete domain is another question.

Comment: Indeed, they are given in [I cannot find reference (paper) of this relation $u(t)t^{α} ↔^{FT} f^{-(α+1)}$](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/74315/15892)

Comment: Well, as proof is a proof, with its hypotheses. It is not harmed  by some signal that satisfies the observations, but does not satisfy some hypothesis. Could you display some data in time and frequency with fits, to be more concrete

Comment: @User_O I don't think you need that your signal is $t^{\alpha}$. In my opinion, this proof uses a syllogism. 1. from $t^{\alpha}$, you find the frequency dependence of the PSD 2. from $t^{\alpha}$, you find the the frequency dependence of the magnitude spectrum of the square of the signal. So, then you can find the magnitude spectrum of the square of the signal starting from the PSD.

Comment: Thank you Luca. My hypothesis is not harmed, because it is just an hypothesis, and second, it is not mine. Anyway, I shall be coming back soon with a kind of stochastic model that could be useful